# Is there an inverse probability mass function for Poisson statistics in Python?

Tags: python, statistics, distribution, poisson

I am looking for an inverse pmf for Poisson statistics. By *inverse* I mean a function `inv_pmf(p, k)` that returns the distribution parameter lambda. For clarity the parameters are used as follows: p = lambda^k / k! * exp(-lambda).
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have equation for probability p(k,λ) = λ<sup>k</sup> e<sup>-λ</sup>/k!. And you know `p` and `k` but want to know `λ`. Well, take log from lhs and rhs and get simple equation.

log(p) = k*log(λ) - λ - log(k!)

or

λ = k*log(λ) - log(p) - log(G(k+1)), where `G()` is Gamma-function, which is available in Python lib. You could plot difference between RHS and LHS and see that it could have multiple solutions. Them using Python fsolve function, you could get root out of that non-linear equation.

Code (Python 3.7, Anaconda, Windows 10 x64)

```
#%%    
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def logrhs(p, k, λ):
    return k*np.log(λ) - math.log(p) - math.lgamma(k+1)

def poissonPMF(k, λ):
    lp = k*np.log(λ) - λ - math.lgamma(k+1)
    return np.exp(lp)

p = 0.2
k = 3.0

λλ = np.linspace(0.001, 10.0, 101)

#%%    
rhs = logrhs(p, k, λλ)
lhs = np.copy(λλ)

pmf = poissonPMF(k, λλ)

plt.plot(λλ, lhs - rhs, 'r')
plt.plot(λλ, pmf, 'g')
plt.show()

# %%
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def f(x):
    return x - logrhs(p, k, x)

starting_guess = 4.0
λ = fsolve(f, starting_guess)
print((λ, poissonPMF(k, λ)))

starting_guess = 1.9
λ = fsolve(f, starting_guess)
print((λ, poissonPMF(k, λ)))
```

As an example, I use k=3 and p=0.2 for a test. For me, it prints two roots

```
(array([3.90263215]), array([0.2]))
(array([2.24859448]), array([0.2]))
```

and verifies that indeed probability is equal to 0.2. GRaph shows red line is crossing 0 in two places
[image]

Comment: Thanks, works fine. But I assume there is no such function implemented in scipy or numpy already? In that case I do need a function like yours.

Comment: @maximumphysics Not that I'm aware of. Note, that is you have all probabilities p_k somehow, you could get back λ as mean value, λ = Sum(0...Infinity) k*p_k. For single value function like mine should work, but problem I demonstrated is quite simple - you can get two answers, so you have to pick up one using some additional (domain specific) knowledge.

Comment: @maximumphysics If you find the answer acceptable, you could accept it following stackoverflow rules https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Severin_Pappadeux Thank you, so I will have to use a function like yours.